# Dynamic array of structs memory storage

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to create a **dynamic array of Clients**, but i am not succeding. This is my code. When i run this code the output is

```
3
� H
3
4332
3
8939
```

I think it's printing memory stuff, however i don't know why. I put my code down here

```
int client_counter = 0;

typedef struct client
{
   char *pid;
   char *message;
}Client;


void store (Client * client_array, char *buf)
{  

   Client c;

   c.pid = strdup (strtok (buf, ":"));

   c.message = strdup (strtok (NULL, "\0"));

   client_array[client_counter++] = c;
}

int main () {
       
  Client* client_array = malloc (sizeof (struct client));

  char buf1[50] = { "1245:message" };
  store (client_array, buf1);
      
  char buf2[50] = { "4332:message" };
      
  store (client_array, buf2);
  char buf3[50] = { "8939:message" };
  store (client_array, buf3);


  for (int i = 0; i < client_counter; i++)
  {
     printf ("%d\n", client_counter);
     printf ("%s\n", client_array[i].pid);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I already tried do use this:

```
    client_array = realloc(client_array, sizeof(struct client) * (client_counter + 1));
```

in store function right after this line.

```
client_array[client_counter++] = c;
```

But it's not working too.

Comment: Re "*right after this line.*", You should allocate memory *before* you need it. Also, I suspect you didn't return the pointer returned by `realloc` back to `main`.

Comment: You have `Client * client_array`, `char *buf` and `Client* client_array`. I don't care if you put spaces on the left, right or both, but pick one and stick with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate extra memory if there's not enough space. Right now, you allocate enough for one, but you try to access three.

Don't forget to return the pointer of the new memory block back to main! In the following, this is done by passing a pointer to the caller's pointer. `store` modifies the caller's pointer via the passed pointer.

```c
// Sets errno and returns 0 on error.
int store(Client ** client_array_ptr, char *buf) {  
   Client* new_client_array = realloc(*client_array_ptr, sizeof(Client) * (client_counter + 1));
   if (!new_client_array)
      return 0;

   *client_array_ptr = new_client_array;
   
   // ...

   new_client_array[client_counter++] = c;
   return 1;
}


int main() {
   Client* client_array = NULL;

   // ...

   if (!store(&client_array, buf1)) {
      perror("malloc");
      exit(1);
   }

   // ...

   if (!store(&client_array, buf2)) {
      perror("malloc");
      exit(1);
   }

   // ...

   free(client_array);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: imagine that i added a client and know i dont need it anymore, how can i free it from the array without losing the other clientes?

Comment: You can realloc to a smaller number. But if you have any elements after the one you want to delete, you'll have to copy them down. For example, if have 4 clients and want to delete the second, you will need to copy 2 into 1 and 3 into 2 before shrinking the buffer. (You technically don't have to shrink the buffer; having extra space at the end isn't a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

The original code does out-of-range access because it is trying to store multiple data in a buffer which is allocated for only one element.

To use `realloc()`, you have to note that arguments of functions in C are *copies* of what are passed. Modifying arguments inside callee function do not affect what is passed in caller. You should pass pointers to what should be modified to have functions modify caller's local things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int client_counter = 0;

typedef struct client
{
   char *pid;
   char *message;
}Client;


void store (Client ** client_array, char *buf)
{  

   Client c;

   c.pid = strdup (strtok (buf, ":"));

   c.message = strdup (strtok (NULL, "\0"));

   *client_array = realloc(*client_array, sizeof(struct client) * (client_counter + 1));
   (*client_array)[client_counter++] = c;
}

int main () {
       
  Client* client_array = malloc (sizeof (struct client));

  char buf1[50] = { "1245:message" };
  store (&client_array, buf1);
      
  char buf2[50] = { "4332:message" };
      
  store (&client_array, buf2);
  char buf3[50] = { "8939:message" };
  store (&client_array, buf3);


  for (int i = 0; i < client_counter; i++)
  {
     printf ("%d\n", client_counter);
     printf ("%s\n", client_array[i].pid);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit more about this "Client ** client_array"?

Comment: It is a pointer to `Client*`. It is used to update the pointer to array of `Client` (`Client*`) to the new value.

Comment: `Client* client_array = malloc (sizeof (struct client));` could be simplified to `Client* client_array = NULL;`. No point in allocating there if you're just going to ask `realloc` to make sure it's allocated a moment later.

Comment: @MikeCAT 1. any reallocation error will lead to the memory leak. 2. Use objects not types in `sizeof` . 3 you never check allocation result. It is an example how it should not be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit different way.

```
typedef struct
{
   char *pid;
   char *message;
}client_TypeDef;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    client_TypeDef clients[];
}clients_TypeDef;

clients_TypeDef *add(clients_TypeDef *clients, const char *pid, const char *message)
{
    size_t newsize = clients ? clients -> size + 1 : 1;
    client_TypeDef client = {.pid = strdup(pid), .message = strdup(message)};

    if(client.pid && client.message)
    {
        clients = realloc(clients, sizeof(*clients) + newsize * sizeof(clients -> clients[0]));

        if(clients)
        {
            clients -> size = newsize;
            clients -> clients[newsize - 1] = client;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        free(client.pid);
        free(client.message);
        clients = NULL;
    }
    return clients;
}
```